# "Edit" button working like a "Add" on Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I writing prject on Java using Spring Boot and Angular, and I've one question about "Edit" button in my project, fact is that she is working like a "Add" button, I mean she to create a new word in my table, and must edit

That's problem not on back side, 'coz I was testing my @Put method by Postman and he is working good and I made a conclusion that this is problem on front side of my program

**My open Modal method in my component**

```
public onOpenModal(word: Word | any, mode: string): void {

    const container = document.getElementById('main-container')

    const button = document.createElement('button');

    button.type = 'button';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');

    if (mode === 'add') {
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addWordModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'update') {
      this.editWord = word;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#editWordModal');
    }
    if (mode === 'delete') {
      this.deleteWord = word;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteWordModal');
    }

    container?.appendChild(button);
    button.click();
  }
```

**My modal windows**

```html
<!-- Add Employee Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addWordModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addWordModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addWordModalLabel">Add Word</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddWord(addForm)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="english word">English word</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel name="englishWord" class="form-control" id="english word" placeholder="english word" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="transcription">Transcription</label>
            <input type="email" ngModel name="transcription" class="form-control" id="transcription" placeholder="Transcription" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="translate word">Translate word</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel name="translateWord" class="form-control" id="translate word" placeholder="Translate word" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="add-word-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Edit Employee Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editWordModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editWordModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editWordModalLabel">Edit Word</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form #editForm="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="englishWord">English word</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel="{{editWord?.englishWord}}" name = "englishWord" class="form-control" id="englishWord" placeholder="english word" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="editTranscription">Transcription</label>
            <input type="email" ngModel="{{editWord?.transcription}}" name = "transcription" class="form-control" id="editTranscription" placeholder="Transcription" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="translateWord">Translate word</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel="{{editWord?.translateWord}}" name = "translateWord" class="form-control" id="translateWord" placeholder="Translate word" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="edit-word-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button (click)="onEditWord(editForm.value)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I try explain my problem one more time using screenshots

[image]

I've that's table where I can add new word in my dictionary

[image]

And when I try to edit a word, the program creates a new word which is the previously edited word
[image]

[image]

[image]

I was trying to edit `word` on `words`

*Word service ts*

```
  public addWord(word: Word): Observable<Word>{
    return this.http.post<Word>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/add`, word);
  }
  public updateWord(word: Word): Observable<Word>{
    return this.http.put<Word>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/update`, word);
  }
```

**Put request using Postman**

[image]

**Put request using UI**

[image]

**Response using UI**

```
{
"id":1008,
"englishWord":"Removed",
"translateWord":"Удалять",
"transcription":"[transcription]",
"wordCode":null
}
```

**onEditMethod**

```
  public onEditWord(word: Word): void {

    this.wordService.updateWord(word).subscribe(
      (response: Word) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getWords();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

[image]

```
Word.ts
____________________

export interface Word{
  id: number;
  englishWord: string;
  translateWord: string;
  transcription: string;
}
```

```
WordService.ts
__________________
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Word} from "./word";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class WordService{
  private apiServerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public mainPage(): Observable<void>{
    return this.http.get<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}`)
  }
  public getWords(): Observable<Word[]>{
    return this.http.get<Word[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/all`);
  }
  public addWord(word: Word): Observable<Word>{
    return this.http.post<Word>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/add`, word);
  }
  public updateWord(word: Word): Observable<Word>{
    return this.http.put<Word>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/update`, word);
  }
  public deleteWord(wordId: number): Observable<void>{
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/dictionary/delete/${wordId}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your record in the DB updating or adding a new record? I want to know if your problem is UI or API.

Comment: If I using my UI, then word to adding to DB, but if I using postman and send PUT request using only API, everything's fine and word updating, so I think that problem in UI

Comment: Can you add what's going on in your `onEditWord()` method?

Comment: Updated my question and added responses from API using postmain and from UI, also I was adding onEditWord() method

Comment: Does it include the id value in the word variable that comes as a parameter to your `onEditWord()` method? I mean the values sent as requests, not the response values.

Comment: Yeap, but I can't delete id value from my Word model because he is necessary for delete method

Comment: Perhaps I can somehow ignoring id value while I editing words?

Comment: No, you need to send the id value. The API needs the id value to determine which value to update.

Comment: What do you see in the payload tab in your screenshot of the update?

Comment: Yes, now I understand. In your PUT request, the Id value is not sent in your request.

Comment: Can you help me fix it? I just so bad in TS :D

Comment: Of course I'll try to help. Can you share the class that belongs to your `Word` object in TS?

Comment: I updated my question and added Word interface and Word service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250708/discussion-between-fatih-and----ii).